# kotlin syntaxes change into viewBinding

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I have made the viewBinding changes in Android Studio. But unfortunately I do not know how to change the following code to viewBinding. Please help me

```
    package com.example.myapplication

     import android.view.LayoutInflater
     import android.view.View
     import android.view.ViewGroup
     import android.widget.BaseAdapter
     import android.widget.TextView


     class Temp(private  val data: List<DataModel>): BaseAdapter() {

override fun getCount(): Int = data.count()

override fun getItem(position: Int): DataModel = data[position]

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long =position.toLong()

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {





    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent !!.context).inflate(R.layout.temp,null)
    val data1 = getItem(position)
    view.proImg.setImageResource()
    return view
}

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44127673/7626390
try this

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent !!.context).inflate(R.layout.temp,null)
```

to

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context)
val view = TempBinding.inflate(inflater, null)
```

and then

```
return view.root
```

also dont forget to import TempBinding

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
val binding = TempBinding.inflate(
    LayoutInflater.from(context)
)
return binding.view
```